# How to calculate the Wald functional?

Tags: gravity, string-theory, entropy, ads-cft, entanglement-entropy

I want to calculate the Wald functional for arbitrary higher curvature Lagrangians - like getting equation 6.31 from 6.30 in this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.7856v1.pdf).
A priori the above looks like an extremely complicated calculation!

Or is there a trick or a software possibly used to get this?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7856

Answer (score 3):

This type of calculation can be done in Mathematica using the [xTensor](http://xact.es/xTensor/) package (its free). There is a bit of a learning curve, but the documentation is great and they have a very active google-group.

Typically you will need to write the Lagrangian explicitly as a polynomial in the Riemann Tensor. Once you do this, the VarD command (xTensor) can handle the variation. For more complicated cases (calculating the second order variation to find the Entanglement Entropy using Xi Dong's method (arxiv:1310.5713), for example), a computer program is absolutely necessary- it would be nearly impossible to do the calculation by hand (in a timely manner).

I have reproduced the equation you were looking for using the xTensor package [here](http://www.mediafire.com/file/x917dv35d2v0oet/R4-Example.nb).

(I would have included more links, by my reputation is too low!)